# Neo4j - Finding the Shortest Path between two nodes based on relationship property

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to figure out if there's someway to get the shortest distance between two nodes based in a relationship sum, given this example:
[neo4j image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiJe1.png)

Code for image above:

```
CREATE (some_point_1:Point {title:'Some Point 1'})
CREATE (some_point_2:Point {title:'Some Point 2'})
CREATE (some_point_3:Point {title:'Some Point 3'})
CREATE (some_point_4:Point {title:'Some Point 4'})
CREATE (some_point_5:Point {title:'Some Point 5'})
CREATE (some_point_6:Point {title:'Some Point 6'})

CREATE (some_point_1)-[:distance {value:100}]->(some_point_2)
CREATE (some_point_2)-[:distance {value:150}]->(some_point_4)
CREATE (some_point_1)-[:distance {value:200}]->(some_point_3)
CREATE (some_point_3)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_4)
CREATE (some_point_2)-[:distance {value:500}]->(some_point_5)
CREATE (some_point_4)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_5)
CREATE (some_point_5)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_6)
CREATE (some_point_6)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_1)
```

In this example the shortest path should be:
some_point_1 > some_point_2 > some_point_4 > some_point_5 (100+150+300 = 550)

Is something like this possible with Cypher?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `shortestPath` function in Cypher does not take into account accumulating of relationship properties, so this:

```
MATCH (start:Point {title: 'Some Point 1'}), (end:Point {title: 'Some Point 5'})
MATCH p=shortestPath((start)-[:distance*]->(end))
RETURN p
```

would find the shortest path from `start` to `end` based on the number of relationships in the path.

You could reduce on the sums of the distances:

```
MATCH (start:Point {title: 'Some Point 1'}), (end:Point {title: 'Some Point 5'})
MATCH p=(start)-[:distance*]->(end)
WITH p,reduce(s = 0, r IN rels(p) | s + r.value) AS dist
RETURN p, dist ORDER BY dist DESC
```

But the problem here is that you need to calculate the total distance for all paths from `start` to `end`. To be more efficient you want to use a graph search algorithm like [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or A*, both of which are implemented in [Neo4j's Java API](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded-graph-algo).

In Neo4j 3.0 these algorithms are exposed in Cypher through the [APOC procedure library](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures). Once you install APOC you can call the procedure from Cypher:

```
MATCH (start:Point {title: 'Some Point 1'}), (end:Point {title: 'Some Point 5'})
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(start, end, 'distance', 'value') YIELD path, weight
RETURN path, weight
```

Comment: Thanks! It woked ^^

Answer (score 1):

Cypher has a shortestPath() function, that combined with predicates and a some trial and error will probably do what you want.

But to save time, it's easier to use [neo4j APOC Procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures), which includes a weighted dijkstra shortest path algorithm that should be a perfect fit for what you want.

I haven't used it yet, but I think the syntax (after matching on startNode and endNode, using the name of your relationship and the property used for weight) is something like

```
CALL apoc.algo.dijkstra(startNode, endNode, 'distance', 'value') 
YIELD path, weight
```

As for taking direction into account, the wiki documentation doesn't say it outright, but it looks like < or > is added to the appropriate end of the relationship label, I think, so 'distance>' is probably the more correct parameter, if you want it to respect direction.