# Neo4jrb - Cypher query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I have a database like in this question:

[Neo4j - Finding the Shortest Path between two nodes based on relationship property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237237/neo4j-finding-the-shortest-path-between-two-nodes-based-on-relationship-proper/38237424)

```
CREATE (some_point_1:Point {title:'Some Point 1'})
CREATE (some_point_2:Point {title:'Some Point 2'})
CREATE (some_point_3:Point {title:'Some Point 3'})
CREATE (some_point_4:Point {title:'Some Point 4'})
CREATE (some_point_5:Point {title:'Some Point 5'})
CREATE (some_point_6:Point {title:'Some Point 6'})

CREATE (some_point_1)-[:distance {value:100}]->(some_point_2)
CREATE (some_point_2)-[:distance {value:150}]->(some_point_4)
CREATE (some_point_1)-[:distance {value:200}]->(some_point_3)
CREATE (some_point_3)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_4)
CREATE (some_point_2)-[:distance {value:500}]->(some_point_5)
CREATE (some_point_4)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_5)
CREATE (some_point_5)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_6)
CREATE (some_point_6)-[:distance {value:300}]->(some_point_1)
```

Now I'm trying to execute a query like this: (from a Rails app)

```
MATCH (start:Point {title: 'Some Point 1'}), (end:Point {title: 'Some Point 5'})
MATCH p=(start)-[:distance*]->(end)
WITH p,reduce(s = 0, r IN rels(p) | s + r.value) AS dist
RETURN p, dist ORDER BY dist DESC
```

I'm trying to do a similar query with the [active model wrapper](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j), but it's not working :(

Is there a way to execute a pure Cypher query from neo4jrb or neo4j-core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do Cypher directly if you want via the `neo4j-core` gem (which you need anyways when using the `neo4j` gem).

For example: `n = Neo4j::Session.query("MATCH (n) RETURN n").first` (assuming you have configured you application to communicate with the Neo4j server).

If you are using the `neo4j` gem you need to have the corresponding `ActiveNode` (and possibly `ActiveRel`) models in your application so that you can do your queries. This gem is pretty much a nice wrapper of the standard `ActiveModel` for Neo4j :)

You have more information on how to: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-core/wiki/Queries
You can also move from a `QueryProxy` chain to a `Neo4j::Core::Query`. See https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Search-and-Match#detailed-querying

Answer (score 0):

MATCH (start:Point {title: 'Some Point 1'}), (end:Point {title: 'Some Point 5'})
MATCH p=(start)-[:distance*]->(end)
WITH p,reduce(s = 0, r IN rels(p) | s + r.value) AS dist
RETURN p, dist ORDER BY dist DESC

Guillermo is absolutely right, but I thought I would give a stab at some code:

```
Point.where(title: 'Some Point 1').connected(:end, :rels, rel_length: :any).where(title: 'Some Point 5')
   .query.with(:p, dist: 'reduce(s = 0, r IN :rels | s + r.value)')
   .return(:p, :dist)
   .order(disc: :desc)
```

That will give you an `Enumerable` which you can iterate over or call `to_a` on.  Or you could return a two dimensional array directly:

```
   .order(disc: :desc)
   .pluck(:p, :dist)
```

This assumes an `ActiveNode` model as Guillermo said.  Something like;

```
class Point
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :title

  has_many :out, :connected, type: :distance, model_class: :Point
end
```

The name of the association may or may not be what you want, I just guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Guillermo is absolutely right, but I thought I would give a stab at some code:

```
Point.where(title: 'Some Point 1').connected(:end, :rels, rel_length: :any).where(title: 'Some Point 5')
   .query.with(:p, dist: 'reduce(s = 0, r IN :rels | s + r.value)')
   .return(:p, :dist)
   .order(disc: :desc)
```

That will give you an `Enumerable` which you can iterate over or call `to_a` on.  Or you could return a two dimensional array directly:

```
   .order(disc: :desc)
   .pluck(:p, :dist)
```

This assumes an `ActiveNode` model as Guillermo said.  Something like;

```
class Point
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :title

  has_many :out, :connected, type: :distance, model_class: :Point
end
```

The name of the association may or may not be what you want, I just guessed.